# При запуске приложения из jar на странице выдает 404

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

Собираю проект на spring boot с помощью maven. Использую встроенный tomcat.

jar стартует, создает базу, видно что spring security работает, редиректит с защищенных страниц, сервлеты инициализируются

Но ни одна страница не отображается

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp
```

Подключение страниц

```
   @Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

    return resolver;
}
```

Подключение ресурсов и скриптов

```
 @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Путь к страницам

```
SpringSec\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\pages\login.jsp
```

ошибка сервлета

```
2016-10-03 15:22:53.387  WARN 5452 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]   o.s.web.servlet.PageNot
Found: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/chat-server-1.0
-SNAPSHOT.jar/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что ваши ресурсы (.jsp в /WEB-INF/pages/) попадают в результирующий джарник?

Comment: Кстати не нашел их там:( Как добавить весь каталог с ресурсами?

Comment: Очевидно, ресурсы приложения не обрабатываются. Чем вы собираете проект?

Comment: с помощью maven

Comment: Вам нужно подключить [resources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/usage.html). У меня сейчас нет времени писать полную инструкцию, но в интернете куча примеров, ЕМНИП его вообще достаточно объявить в `<build>`, и все заработает.

Comment: Ресурсы подключил но там теперь сервлет ругается

Comment: попробуй собрать через mvn package

Answer (score 0):

Сообщение с `Whitelabel Error Page` показывает spring boot, т.е. tomcat запустился и работает, но не работает мапинг урлов. Каталог `/WEB-INF/` является приватным и не доступен из вне. Покажите свой web.xml и то как замапили урлы.

Comment: дополнительные сведения в вопроса